# Displaying Different Screens in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

Recently started working with XNA (coming from java) and run into a problem with displaying game screens. When loading up XNA I get given a game.cs class which I interpreted to be a set a functions for drawing a single self-contained screen in the game. As obviously typing the code for all your different screens into this single class would get very messy very quickly so I created the below class to handle changes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Colonies
{
    public class GameManager //manages game screens
    {
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game currentScreen;

        public enum screens { menu, game, summary };

        public GameManager()
        {
            initialize();
        }

        public void initialize()
        {
            currentScreen = new Menu(this);
            ((Menu)currentScreen).Run();
        }

        public void changeScreen(int i) 
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    currentScreen = new Menu(this);
                    ((Menu)currentScreen).Run();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    currentScreen = new World(this);
                    ((World)currentScreen).Run();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    currentScreen = new Summary(this);
                    ((Summary)currentScreen).Run();
                    break;
            }
        }
}
```

}

However when one of these changes is triggered this causes an error flag up telling me I can't call game run more than once. Does this mean by initial estimation about having a single all purpose game screen is actually correct?! Should be manager instead be being queried for game like screens which methods are then called in the main game.cs class?

i.e.

in game.cs update method for example:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Allows the game to exit
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();

    // TODO: Add your update logic here
    aGameManager.getAGameObject.DoAnUpdate();
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

So essentially my main game class is never run again but just changes what it displays. Would this be the correct solution? (So much of the game class is hidden I am not sure what is the correct way to use it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Game` class is *the entire game*. That's why it's called `Game`. If you want, you can create 'screen' objects, that each control a different screen, and use the `Game` class as you were trying to use the 'game manager'.

EG:

```
public static int currentScreen = 0; // Any screen can change this variable when needed


List<Screenobject> myscreens = new List<Screenobject>(); // Populate this with screens
// OR
menuscreen = new menuScreen();
otherscreen = new otherScreen();
// ...


protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
      myscreens[currentScreen].Update(gameTime);
      // OR
      switch (currentScreen)
      {
          case 1:
               menuscreen.Update(gameTime); break;
          // ...
      }
      base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

and `Draw(..)` the same as `Update(..)`

Answer (score 0):

create enumerator

```
enum gamestate
   mainmenu
   gameplay
   options
end enum
```

and then simply in your update (draw) main functions

```
if gamestate = mainmenu then mainmenu.update();
if gamestate = gameplay then gameplay.update()
```

Comment: That is not valid C# code, and, even if it was, would be of absolutely no help to this question.

Comment: there is no C# tag in question, and this is pseudo code to give a hint how to do it. there is no need to write whole game code.

Comment: XNA is a C#-based game framework. And your "pseudo-code" is, again, not relevant or helpful. If you don't know what the only tag on a question means, figure out what it means before posting an answer.

Comment: well, i'm using XNA on VB... ok, i will vote up your masterpiece.